# Prove that if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $na_n \to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence of nonnegative real numbers.
>
> Prove that if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $na_n \to 0$.
>
> Hint: use that $n\, a_{2n} \le a_{n+1}+\cdots + a_{2n}$

I couldn't prove this using the given hint, could someone give me a few tips?

I also have two more questions:

- Suppose I have $2na_{2n},(2n+1)a_{2n+1}\to 0$ is that enough to say that $na_n\to 0$?
- Is there any easy way to show $n \, a_{2n}\le a_{n+1}+\cdots + a_{2n}$, there's probably a simple inductive proof I couldn't get.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369669/if-a-n-is-a-decreasing-sequence-of-strictly-positive-numbers-and-if-suma?rq=1

Comment: How do you get $\leq 2a_{n+1}$? It's not possible for $2(a_{n+1}+\text{ positive values})\leq 2a_{n+1}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Whoops, I meant $2na_{n+1}$, but in that case I can say nothing...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $(R_N)_N$ be the sequence of remainders of your series, namely
$$\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\ R_N=\sum_{n=N+1}^{+\infty}a_n.$$
Since your series converges, the sequence $(R_N)_N$ is well defined and
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}R_N=0.$$
Now, since your $a_n$'s are non-negative and the sequence is non-increasing,
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\ na_{2n}\leq a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{2n}\leq R_n.$$
By the Squeeze Theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}na_{2n}=0.$$

For the odd subsequence: write, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$(2n+1)a_{2n+1}=2na_{2n+1}+a_{2n+1}\leq2na_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$$
and conclude (by the Squeeze Theorem again) that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(2n+1)a_{2n+1}=0.$$

Finally, you have a sequence $(na_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the odd and even subsequences have a nil limit: you can conclude that the sequence $(na_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a nil limit.

---

Regarding your questions:

- Suppose I have $2na_{2n}\to0$ and $(2n+1)a_{2n+1}\to0$; is that enough to say that $na_n\to0$?

Yes: a sequence has a limit $\ell$ if and only if its odd and even subsequences have the same limit, equal to $\ell$. Apply this result to the sequence $(na_n)_n$.

- Is there any easy way to show $na_{2n}\leq a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{2n}$, there's probably a simple inductive proof I couldn't get.

You don't need induction here. Since the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is non-decreasing,
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\ a_{n+1}\geq a_{n+2}\geq\cdots\geq a_{2n},$$
hence
$$a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{2n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k\geq\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_{2n}=na_{2n}.$$

Comment: Could you explain how to get $R_n\to 0$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Sure: Call $(S_N)_N$ the sequence of partial sums, namely $$S_N=\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n,$$ and call $S$ the sum of the series, namely $$S=\lim_{N\to+\infty} S_N.$$ We clearly have: $$\forall N\in\mathbb{N}, S=S_N+R_N$$ or, equivalently, $R_N=S-S_N$. Hence $$\lim_{N\to+\infty}R_N=S-S=0.$$

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks a lot gniourf.