# Prove or disprove: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{a_n} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to determine whether the following statement is true or false:

> Let $a_n$ be an unbounded non decreasing sequences s.t. $\sum
>  \frac{1}{\log(a_n)}$ converges.
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{a_n} = 0$.

Since $\sum \frac{1}{\log(a_n)}$ converges, $\log(a_n)$ must be asymptotic greater than $n$, so $a_n$ must be asymptotic greater than $2^{n}$.

Is the answer that simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the sequence $(\log a_n)^{-1}$ is nonicreasing the convergence of the series implies [(see)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668003/limit-of-na-n)
$$\lim_n {n\over \log a_n}=0 $$  Therefore
$${n\over \log a_n}<{1\over 2},\quad n>N$$ i.e.
$$a_n>e^{2n},\quad n>N$$ and the conclusion follows.

**Remark** The assumption that $a_n$ is nondecreasing is essential. For example let
$$a_n=\begin{cases} e^{n^2} & n\neq 2^{k^2}\\
n & n=2^{k^2}
\end{cases} $$
Then $\sum (\log a_n)^{-1}<\infty$ but for $n=2^{k^2}$ we have $${2^n\over a_n}={2^{2^{k^2}}\over a_{2^{k^2}}}={2^{2^{k^2}}\over 2^{k^2}}\to \infty $$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=e^{n^2}$ . $\sum\frac{1}{log({a_n})}=\sum\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{2^n}=\infty$. So it's not true

Comment: There was a typo, $a_n$ should be bellow $2^n$. My bad.