# Does $\sum\frac{1}{nf(n) \log(n)}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $f$ be an unbounded non-decreasing function s.t.
> $\sum\frac{1}{2^{f(n)}}$ converges.
>
> Does $\sum\frac{1}{nf(n) \log(n)}$ converge?

My thoughts:

Since $\sum\frac{1}{2^{f(n)}}$ converges, then $\ logn = O(f(n))$, otherwise it will diverge.

And now we can use comparison test to find an upper bound using $a_n = 1/n \log^2n$.

Am I correct?

thanks.

Comment: Presumably the sums start at $n=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption that $f(n)$ is non decreasing is essential in order to show that $\log n=O(f(n)).$

The condition $\sum 2^{-f(n)}<\infty$ combined with the  monotonicity assumption imply ([see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668003/limit-of-na-n))
$${n\over 2^{f(n)}}\to 0$$
Hence $$\log n =o(f(n))$$ and the conclusion follows by the comparison test, as observed by OP.