# If a series $\sum\lambda_n$ of positive terms is convergent, does the sequence $n\lambda_n$ converge to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\lambda_n>0, n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $\sum_n \lambda_n<+\infty$.

Can I conclude that $n\lambda_n\to 0$?

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369669/if-a-n-is-a-decreasing-sequence-of-strictly-positive-numbers-and-if-suma) and their answers, it is shown that this is true if $\lambda_n$ are decreasing. What happens if $\lambda_n$ are not decreasing?

Comment: Of it didn't, then $\lambda_n$ would be on the order of $\frac{1}{n}$ and therefore the sum would diverge

Comment: It is rather distressing to me how many smart people have gotten this innocuous problem completely wrong.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki As a university student, I can say that I've seen very intelligent professors sometimes make "trivial" mistakes. We're all human, I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Define $\lambda_n$ by stating that $\lambda_{2^n}=2^{-n}$ and $\lambda_k=2^{-k}$ for other values of $k$.

Then $2^n\lambda_{2^n}=1$ so there is no convergence to $0$.

It is evident however that $\sum_n\lambda_n<\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider
$$
\lambda_n=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\frac1n&\text{if $n=k^2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
\frac1{n^2}&\text{if $n\ne k^2$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then, when $n=k^2$,
$$
n\lambda_n=1
$$
yet
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda_n=2\zeta(2)-\zeta(4)
$$

---

However, if we have $\lambda_k\ge\lambda_{k+1}$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\lambda_n=0
$$
Suppose not. Then there is an $\epsilon\gt0$ so that for any $n$, there is an $N\ge n$ so that $N\lambda_N\ge\epsilon$. Then, because of the monotonicity, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=N/2}^{N}\lambda_k
&\ge\sum_{k=N/2}^{N}\frac\epsilon{N}\\
&\ge\frac\epsilon2
\end{align}
$$
and since we can choose $n$ as large as we want, there is a limitless set of sequences of terms whose sum is at least $\frac\epsilon2$. That is, we can choose $n_{j+1}=2N_j+2$ so that $N_{j+1}/2\ge n_{j+1}/2\gt N_j$, so that the intervals $[N_j/2,N_j]$ are disjoint and $\sum\limits_{k=N_j/2}^{N_j}\lambda_k\ge\frac\epsilon2$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k=\infty
$$
**Note:** this latter argument is similar to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/369824).

Comment: $\lambda_n > 0$?

Comment: @AOrtiz: okay, if you must quibble about that, I have changed the other terms to be bigger. It still converges, and the limit is not $0$. We need monotonicity, or something similar, to guarantee that $n\lambda_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Is the sequence $\lambda_n$ in the second part of your answer the same as the sequence in the first part? I am also confused by your claim. $\lambda_n\to 0$ because the series converges. You probably want to claim $\lim n\lambda_n = 0$?

Comment: @AOrtiz: no. In the first part, I have given a sequence where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\lambda_n\ne0$ yet the sum converges. In the latter part, I have shown that the conclusion is true if the sequence is monotonic.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Other than the fact that I missed that the terms must be $\gt0$ instead of $\ge0$, there was nothing wrong with my initial answer. I have even shown a positive result for monotonic sequences.

Comment: Neither do I. The difference between $>0$ and $\geq0$ is actually not relevant here (+1).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean "and since we can choose $n$ as large as we want, there is a limitless set of sequences of terms whose sum is at least $\epsilon/2$." I am having difficulty parsing this since it is not precise.

Comment: @AOrtiz: I have added a bit of explanation to the answer. Please let me know if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @AOrtiz: if you still have questions, you can also look at the answer I cited, which follows the same argument.