# Is this statement about sequences true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to establish if the following statement is true.

If $ a_{n}$ is a sequence of real postive numbers such that $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} <\infty, $ than $ a_{n} = o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right). $

If it is not true, can anyone show me a counterexample?

Comment: This is identical  to a [deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2377910) (which had some decent answers). I suggest that [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) be added to this question, or it may suffer the same fate.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the sequence given by $a_n=n^{-1}$ if $n$ is a perfect square and $a_n=0$ otherwise. Then it is easy to see that $\sum a_n<\infty$ but $na_n\not\to 0$

Comment: Could you explain me why $ \sum a_{n} < \infty? $ i was thinking about $ \sum \frac{1}{n^{3}}. $ It is convergent and $n\cdot(n^3)\nrightarrow 0. $ It is wrong?

Comment: You should define $a_n =1/2^n$ or something for $n$ not a perfect square.

Comment: My bad thought positive meant non-negative. If you need strictly positive go with zhw's comment