# $\sum u_n$ converge iff $\sum n(u_n-u_{n+1})$ converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence and $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$.

Prove that: $\sum u_n $ converges iff $\sum n(u_n-u_{n+1})$ converges.

The $\to$ way is simple to check:
$\sum _{k = 1}^{n} n(u_n-u_{n+1}) = -nu_{n+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{k} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{k} u_n,$ since the term on the right side is bounded and the one on the left side is always positive, we have the convergence.

But I have trouble working on the other way. If we can prove $\sum n(u_n-u_{n+1})$ converge implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} nu_n = 0,$ the other way will be proved.

Comment: Can you show/sketch your proof for $\rightarrow$? It could help.

Comment: $\sum _{k = 1}^{n} n(u_n-u_{n+1}) = -nu_{n+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{k} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{k} u_n$, since the term on the right side is bounded and the one on the left side is always positif, we have the convergence.

Comment: If we can prove $\sum n(u_n-u_{n+1})$ converge implies that $lim_{n\to\infty} nu_n = 0$, the other way will be proved

Comment: It's enough to show that convergence of  $\sum n (u_n - u_{n + 1})$ implies $n u_{n  +1}$ is bounded. Remember, we have a nonnegative sequence, so showing that \sum u_n is bounded implies convergence.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that $nu_n$ remains bounded. Fix $n$. Let $b_k = k(u_k - u_{k+1})$ and $B(t) = \sum_{k \leq t} b_k$. [Partial summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) gives
$$\begin{align*}
u_n &= u_{n+L+1} + \sum_{k=n}^{n+L} \frac{b_k}k \\
&= u_{n+L+1} + \frac{B(n+L)}{n+L} - \frac{B(n-1)}{n-1} + \int_{n-1}^{n+L} \frac{B(t)}{t^2} dt \\
&\leq u_{n+L+1} + \frac{B(n+L)}{n+L} + B(\infty) \int_{n-1}^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2} \\
&\leq u_{n+L+1} + \frac{B(\infty)}{n+L} + \frac{B(\infty)}{n-1}
\end{align*}$$
Now take $L$ sufficiently large so that $n u_{n+L+1} \leq 1$.

Comment: I've come up with a proof:
Let $v_n = n(u_n-u_{n_1})$, then $\frac{v_n}{n} \leq v_n$, so $\sum \frac{v_n}{n}$ converges, noting the sum by S.
So we can write $u_n = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{v_k}{k} \leq \frac{\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} v_k}{n} \leq \frac{S}{n}$, so $nu_n \leq S$.

Comment: @pojoo You can write a separate answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nu_k-\sum_{k=1}^nk(u_k-u_{k+1})
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(ku_{k+1}-(k-1)u_k)\\
&=nu_{n+1}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/369824) shows that if $u_n$ is a decreasing sequence and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nu_k$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nu_n=0$.

Suppose that $u_n$ is a decreasing sequence and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk(u_k-u_{k+1})$ converges, then
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}nu_n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=n}^\infty(u_k-u_{k+1})\\
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty k(u_k-u_{k+1})\\[6pt]
&=0\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Thus, if either sum converges, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nu_n=0$, and $(1)$ shows that the other sum also converges.

Answer (score 0):

We invoke the following easy-to-prove theorem.

> **Tonelli's Theorem for Series.** Let $a_{m,n} \geq 0$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
> $$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{m,n}
> = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{m,n} $$
> regardless of whether they are finite or not.
>
> *Proof.* Write $S_{M,N}=\sum_{m=1}^{M}\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{m,n}$ and notice that
> $$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{m,n} = \sup_{M \geq 1}\sup_{N\geq 1} S_{M,N} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{m,n} = \sup_{N\geq 1}\sup_{M \geq 1} S_{M,N}. $$
> Then the desired conclusion follows by noting that supremums can be taken in arbitrary order without changing the value. $\square$

Using this, we find that whenever $u_n$ is non-negative and non-increasing,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (u_n - u_{n+1})
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ k \leq n\}} (u_n - u_{n+1}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ k \leq n\}} (u_n - u_{n+1}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (u_k - u_{\infty}),
\end{align*}

where $u_{\infty} := \lim_{n\to\infty} u_n$. So, if in addition that $u_{\infty} = 0$ holds, then this implies

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (u_n - u_{n+1}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u_k $$

regardless of the convergence of each side, and so, the desired claim follows.

---

For a more classical solution, check this:

Let $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers which is non-increasing and $u_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Then, As OP noted, summation by parts shows that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} n (u_n - u_{n+1})
= - N u_{N+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} u_n
\leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} u_n, \tag{1}$$

and so, the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n$ implies that of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(u_n - u_{n+1})$. Conversely, note that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (u_n - u_{n+1})
&= \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} n (u_n - u_{n+1}) \right) + \left( \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} n (u_n - u_{n+1}) \right) \\
&\geq \left( - N u_{N+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} u_n \right) + \left( \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} N (u_n - u_{n+1}) \right) \\
&= \left( - N u_{N+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} u_n \right) + N u_{N+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{N} u_n,
\end{align*}

The second step follows from $\text{(1)}$ together with non-negativity of $u_n - u_{n+1}$, and the third step follows from the assumption that $u_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore this shows that the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(u_n - u_{n+1})$ implies that of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another answer.

> Suppose $a_n\searrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. $\sum_n a_n<\infty$ iff $na_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ and $\sum_n n(a_n-a_{n+1})<\infty$.

First, using Abel's summation by parts we have
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{k=1}a_k=\sum^N_{k=1}(k-(k-1))a_k=\sum^{N-1}_{k=1}k(a_k-a_{k+1}) + Na_N \tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}

Sufficiency is then clear from \eqref{one}

To prove necessity, it is enough to show that $na_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. Recall that from Cauchy's condensation theorem, convergence of $\sum_na_n$ and the fact that $a_n$ is nonincreasing is equivalent to convergence of $\sum_k 2^k a_{2^k}$. This in particular implies that $2^ka_{2^k}\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}0$. Now, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a unique $k_n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that
$2^{k_n}\leq n< 2^{k_n +1}$; hence
$$na_n\leq na_{2^{k_n}}\leq 2\,2^{k_n}a_{2^{k_n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
The desired conclusion follows.