# Problem showing a certain series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show the series ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin\left(nx\right)}$
 converges for all $x\in\left[0,2\pi\right]$. Using Dirchlet's Test it suffices to show that the series of partial sums of ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(nx\right)}$
  is bounded but I can't seem to manage to show that. I saw a solution that uses some complex number identities but I really would prefer to avoid using complex numbers.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Compare $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin(nx)$ with $\dfrac{1}{n}$ and use the comparation test; also note that $|\sin(nx)|\leq1$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108486/sx-sum-n-1-inftya-n-sinnx-a-n-is-monotonic-decreasing-a-n-to-0/108586#108586). Note this will show convergence on $(0,2\pi)$; of course, the series converges at $0$ and $2\pi$ as well.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}$  does not converge though...

Comment: Yes, my bad. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh that is a nice one.
Taking $$ \sin(kx)=\frac{\cos\bigl((k-\frac{1}{2})x\bigr)-\cos\bigl((k+\frac{1}{2})x\bigr)}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}$$
you can see that $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx)\right|\leq\left|\frac{1}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right|$$ 
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ if $x\neq 2 \pi k $ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: (+1): So, for this problem, that's all you need in order to show convergence for $x\in(0,2\pi)$, and it's immediate for $x=0,x=2\pi$.

Comment: Using Trig identities has always been my weak spot. Very nice solution though, thanks to all the helpers!

Comment: Im not following. You used a telescoping series? Because the limit of the second term does not converge.

Comment: To show the inequality written above he indeed used the fact it's a telescoping sum. Note that the series $sin(kx)$ does not converge but for Dirchlet's Test you only need to show that its partial sums are bounded, which is what was shown here.