# Partial sums of $\sin(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it true that 
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k) \right|\leq M
$$
for every $n$?

I tried comparing this to the integral $\int_2^\infty \sin(x)dx$ but it is not monotone.

This is part of a problem that says if $A_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$ and $|A_n|\leq M$ and $b_n$ is a decreasing sequence to zero, then $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.  Then use this to show that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{\log(n)}
$$

Comment: Using the formula http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+sin(kx)+for+k+%3D+1+to+n

Comment: Yes.  The standard way to show this is to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik}$ using the geometric series formula and then draw a conclusion on the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: You could also argue as I do [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108486/sx-sum-n-1-inftya-n-sinnx-a-n-is-monotonic-decreasing-a-n-to-0/108586#108586).

Comment: Great!  Thanks for that !

Comment: This is know as [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).