# Does the sum $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^{\alpha}}$ converge for $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$ and $x \in [0,2 \pi]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

Does the series
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^{\alpha}},
$$ 
converge for all $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$  and for all $x \in [0,2 \pi]$?

It is obvious that it does when $\alpha > 1$, but I have no idea how to deal with the case
$$
\frac{1}{2} < \alpha \le 1. 
$$

I already appreciate your hints/ideas.

Comment: Did you try replacing $\sin(kx)$ by $e^{ikx}$? This is probably some Fourier fact or something, since for $\alpha > \frac 12$ you have $\sum_{k \ge 1} \left( \frac 1{k^{\alpha}} \right)^2 < \infty$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thanks, but after replacing with $\frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2i}$ how should I go on .... ?

Comment: [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) plus the fact the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n sin(kx)$ are bounded is enough to show convergence for $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: @achille hui : How do you show the partial sums are bounded? I don't believe this statement.

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : You're gonna have 
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}^* \frac{k/|k|}{2i |k|^{\alpha}} e^{ikx}
$$
where $^*$ means you remove the term $k=0$. Do the sum of the absolute value of the squares of the coefficients give you a finite series? Then use Fourier.

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity: this will help you(believe):http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108486/sx-sum-n-1-inftya-n-sinnx-a-n-is-monotonic-decreasing-a-n-to-0/108586#108586

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva see the proof in Salech's link.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, this sum converges for every $\alpha>0$.

**Step I.** *For every $x\in\mathbb R$, the sequence $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\sin kx$ is bounded.*

Indeed, if $x=m\pi$, then $s_n=0$. If  $x\ne m\pi$, then $\sin(x/2)\ne 0$, and
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\sin kx=\mathrm{Im}\left(\mathrm{e}^{xi}+\mathrm{e}^{2xi}+\cdots\mathrm{e}^{nxi}\right)=
\mathrm{Im}\left(\mathrm{e}^{xi}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{nxi}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{xi}-1}\right)
$$
But
$$
\left|\mathrm{e}^{xi}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{nxi}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{xi}-1}\right|\le \frac{2}{|\mathrm{e}^{xi}-1|}=\frac{2}{|\mathrm{e}^{xi/2}-\mathrm{e}^{-xi/2}|}=\frac{1}{|\sin (x/2)|}.
$$
and hence $\lvert s_n\rvert\le \lvert\sin(x/2)\rvert^{-1}$.

**Step II.** *Use Abel's summation method.*
\begin{align}
\sigma_n &=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k^\alpha}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_k-s_{k-1}}{k^\alpha}
=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_k}{k^\alpha}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_{k-1}}{k^\alpha} \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_k}{k^\alpha}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{s_{k}}{{(k+1)}^\alpha}=
\frac{s_n}{n^a}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_k\left(\frac{1}{k^a}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^a}\right).
\end{align}
But
$$
\frac{1}{k^\alpha}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^\alpha}\le\frac{a}{k^{1+\alpha}},
$$
and hence the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}s_n\left(\frac{1}{n^a}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}\right),
$$
converges (indeed absolutely) due to the comparison test.

**Note.** This series converges conditionally and pointwise. It does not converge absolutely, but it does converge uniformly far from zero, i.e., in any interval
$[\varepsilon,2\pi-\varepsilon]$.

Comment: $\frac 1{\sin(x/2)}$ is not bounded. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: The sequence $\{s_n\}$ is bounded. I proved that the series converges for every $x$ - It does not converge uniformly.

Comment: So you mean $\{s_n(x)\}$ is bounded for each $x$?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Correct - What kind of convergence are you looking for?

Comment: It's okay, I read your proof more carefully and now I agree ; it just felt a bit unbelievable that you pushed to $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: you could simply refer to the [Dirichlet Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), which you've essentially proven above.

Comment: @robjohn: Correct.

Answer (score 4):

The set $\{ e^{inx} \, | \, n \in \mathbb Z \}$ forms an Hilbert basis of $L^2([0,2\pi])$ which means that for a function $f \in L^2([0,2\pi])$, we have
$$
f = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \langle f, e_n \rangle e_n
$$
with 
$$
\langle f,e_n\rangle = \frac{n/|n|}{2i n^{\alpha}}
$$
if $n \neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise, if and only if
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |\langle f,e_n \rangle|^2 < \infty.
$$
Since $\alpha > \frac 12$, in our situation this is the case, therefore $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^{\alpha}}$ is well-defined and converges pointwise almost everywhere to some function $f(x)$ which is in $L^2([0,2\pi])$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: $L^2$ convergence of the Fourier series does not imply pointwise convergence in all points, if I don't misremember.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : It doesn't imply pointwise convergence to the considered function whose Fourier series we take (not here, but in the theory of "computing the Fourier series of a function", which is not what I do here), but it definitely converges pointwise to some function. $L^2$ convergence means $L^2$ convergence, so the series must converge to some element of $L^2$. That's all I need.

Comment: No, not in general. See e.g. Theorem 5.12 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. The Fourier series of a continuous function is in general (meaning outside a meagre subspace of $C(T)$) unbounded in every point of a dense $G_\delta$. Since $C(T) \subset L^2(T)$, the existence of $L^2$ Fourier series that don't converge pointwise everywhere follows.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : Yeah you made me doubt. I mean, I wrote things down and then gave it some thought. My proof only tells us that for "almost all $x$" (in the Lebesgue-measure sense) the series converge. I edited my answer and left it there for fun, but Yiorgis's answer is better.

Comment: It's also because I thought "this was the proof" because of the $\alpha > 1/2$ condition.